# Leonardo da Vinci

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I just got done with sequence 1 in AC2, and I noticed that I have a document called a codex. But I can't read the codex and it tells me that I have to find Leonardo da Vinci to decrypt it for me. I remember doing a scene clear back at the first of sequence 1 where I helped Ezio's mom and Leonardo, but I haven't seen him since.

Do I just need to hang on to the codex until something occurs in the storyline that lets me decrypt it, or can I somehow find Leonardo right now and have him do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storyline will guide you to him later. From the way the storyline runs, I doubt you're able to go to him earlier (though I don't know for sure).

Comment: Yep, be patient, the story always drives you through the game. You will see a `L`marker on the map when you'll be able to go to him.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all the pages of the codex.  Once that's done, you can go to Venezia and talk to Leonardo.  He is in the same room as Claudia.